# Automatically update JavaScript object property when another object's property is set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects, each containing a property named `title`.
The `title` property can hold one of two possible string values - `"main"` or `"local"`. Only a single element in the array can have `"main"` as its `title` value at a given time, and the rest of the elements should have their `title` property set to `"local"`.

For instance, take the following array:

```
var locations = [
  {
    title:"main",
    place:"UK"
  },
{
    title:"local",
    place:"USA"
  },
{
    title:"local",
    place:"RUSSIA"
  }
]
```

When setting the `place:"USA"` object's `title` property to `"main`", I want `place:"UK"` object's `title` property to automatically be set to `"local"`.

How to achieve this with javascript?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to swap the values? like `main` inplace of `local` and vice versa.

Comment: Yes i want to swap the values... If i change place USA object title is main means, other object title should be change it local

Comment: If you try to make `main` as `local` then what should happen ?

Comment: How you are changing place ?

Comment: Nope. Place won't change

Comment: Would it be possible to change your `location` variable to an object instead of an array? Because it would be easier to call a `main` object key instead of iterating over the array and checking for the value of `title`.

Comment: No. It should be array

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is set all `title` values to `local`, before setting desired object to `main`.
Another way is to remember which index is currently set to `main` and revert it to local when `main` is to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return a copy of your array with the desired changes:

With ES6/Babel:

```
// Example:
somePlace = 'USA';

const newLocations = locations.map(l =>
  { ...l, title: l.place === somePlace ? 'main' : 'local' }
);
```

With Vanilla JS/Lodash:

```
// Example:
somePlace = 'USA';

var newLocations = _.map(locations, function (l) {
  return _.assign({}, l, { title: l.place === somePlace ? 'main' : 'local' });
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newMainIndex = 2;
var locations = [
  {
    title:"main",
    place:"UK"
  },
{
    title:"local",
    place:"USA"
  },
{
    title:"local",
    place:"RUSSIA"
  }
];

for(var i=0, len=locations.length;i<len;i++){
    locations[i].title = i === newMainIndex ? "main" : "local";
}
```